# logrotate codeigniter logs, keep 7 days only

Tags: logrotate

I'm trying to rotate logs produced by CodeIgniter, they are named this way (one per day)

```
log-2020-05-05.php
log-2020-05-06.php
log-2020-05-07.php
```

The idea is to package this in a debian package for kalkun.
I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17402464) but it doesn't respond my needs

So what I expect is:

- rotate each log file (which is anyway produced only for that day)
- keep at max 7 days of logs, for ex, on May/07 I would like to have the logs up to May/01, and all previous ones deleted

Result would look like this at max (all previous files are expected to be removed)

```
log-2020-05-01.php.1.gz
log-2020-05-02.php.1.gz
log-2020-05-03.php.1.gz
log-2020-05-04.php.1.gz
log-2020-05-05.php.1.gz
log-2020-05-06.php.1.gz
log-2020-05-07.php
```

Is this actually possible with only logrotate ?

The problem is that if I rotate on 'log-*.php' with 'rotate 7', since each file is produced only for a given day, it will actually never rotate a 2nd time, except if I use "create", but that will create empty files, which will pollute the log dir. I could also add "maxage 7" (in addition to "create", but still this will pollute the logdir with empty files)

I tried it this way

```
/var/www/kalkun/application/logs/log-*.php {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    #create 644 www-data www-data
    nocreate
    sharedscripts

    postrotate
        if invoke-rc.d apache2 status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
            invoke-rc.d apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1; \
        fi;
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to rotate logs for a product that has enough sense to do it itselves?   First check if CodeIgniter can be configured to keep only 7 days of logs;

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be configured to rotate. One can configure the path and the extension only

Comment: Any manual online somewhere?

Comment: Sure: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html Code is here https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1-stable/system/core/Log.php